# URL mapping in .NET website

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, webforms, sitemap

In a WebForms .NET website, is there a way to store the URL structure on one place and let some class determine URLs?

I currently have this:

```
NextCar.NavigateUrl = "~/Car.aspx?id=" + carId + "&page=" + (PageId + 1);
```

But I would prefer something like this:

```
NextCar.NavigateUrl = SiteMap.CurrentUrl.Set('page', PageId + 1);
```

or

```
NextCar.NavigateUrl = SiteMap.CarUrl(carId, PageId)
```

This way, I can store my URLs on one place and also generate a menu or sitemap automatically.

Comment: It may be not exactly what you are looking for, but a worth to consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent to this is ASP.NET routing. It's best used with URLs of the format `/Car/{carId}/{pageId}` but it can be persuaded to work with query parameters if you really need them (basically, if you create a path with an unrecognised route value then it will add it to the querystring). The MSDN article "Walkthrough: Using ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms Application" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx is a good starting point.